# Загрузка xml в таблицу бд Oracle с помощью sqlldr

Tags: sql, oracle

Здравствуйте. Я использую Oracle 11g xe. Мне нужно скриптом загрузить xml файл в таблицу. Создал xml. Создал таблицу с двумя полями: test3_id - первичный ключ, и name с типом XMLTYPE. На сколько я понял в такого типа поле должна храниться xml-ка. Нашёл исполнительный код и записал его в txt файл. Вот его текст:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE test3
APPEND
XMLType(name)(
lobfn FILLER CHAR TERMINATED BY ',',
name LOBFILE(lobfn) TERMINATED BY EOF
)
BEGINDATA
D:\\file.xml
```

Запустил его с помощью sqlldr и запись вроде прошла:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда смотрю в данные таблицы там пусто и нечего не добавилось. Но создался bad файл с текстом : D:\file.xml
Возможно я что то сделал не так. Кто знает в чём причина того что данных нет в таблице подскажите пожалуйста. Структура таблицы: test3_id - первичный ключ, name - поле с типом XMLTYPE. Спасибо за ответы заранее.

Comment: А почему бы и нет. xml же просто как текст пишется, какая разница какого она размера. `insert into test3 values(test3_seq.NextVal, XMLType('<test id="1"><data>123</data></test>'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в таблице есть ID, но надо обеспечить его инкрементирование, в случае если во входных данных нет готового ID. Для этого создаем sequence, например `create sequence test3_seq`. Если входные XML находятся в отдельных файлах, то скрипт загрузчика выглядит так:

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
INFILE *
INTO TABLE test3 APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (
test3_id expression "TEST3_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
lob_name FILLER char,
name LOBFILE(lob_name) TERMINATED BY EOF)
BEGINDATA
file1.xml
file2.xml
...
```